# How to create a true/false statement to label significant genes in r?

Tags: r

I would like to find a way to automatically label the up and down regulated genes in my VP, I have been doing it manually looking at the data table. However, Im not sure how to write a command to tell r to label my genes of interest.

```
structure(list(log2FC = c(-0.0794009, -0.113568, 0.615316, -1.16623,
-0.32056, -0.206217, -0.0100415, -0.0448286, -0.0486388, -0.0756063,
-0.0728393, 0.315451, 0.0426718, 0.639178, 0.0925341, 0.0450367,
0.006901, -0.0429835, 0.134707, 0.162444, 0.212584, 0.165407,
-0.0872685, 0.679763, 0.389217, -0.033093, -0.152635, -0.0211448,
0.0847027, -0.195283, 0.0832398, -0.013115, -0.100765, -0.0671384,
-0.329955, 0.0578964, -0.0457076, -0.462796, 0.316622, NA, -0.0127716,
0.15966, NA, 0.447555, -0.00621892, 0.0649842, -0.332575, NA,
0.320113, 0.589376, -0.162403, NA, -0.242632, -0.0594681, 0.0641964,
0.172721, -0.12879, -0.247723, 0.0341975, 0.948706, -0.362608,
0.0129117, 0.148919, 0.39596, -0.170329, 0.192233, 0.0750046,
0.239356, -0.113177, 0.184563, -0.0462517, 0.111383, 0.111771,
0.160304, -0.000317698, -0.0305621, 0.0506452, -0.0694846, -0.122766,
0.127085, -0.737947, 0.0698927, 0.16994, -0.291991, -0.12592,
-0.198342, -0.273148, -0.224852, -0.148406, 0.0278062, -0.12111,
0.154747, -0.0123293, -0.174397, -0.296173, -0.142334, 0.002339,
-0.28758, -0.00561539, 0.351303), logpv = c(0.117565320209322,
0.369598291242942, NA, 0.751054703257298, 2.22594458046808, 0.31656749829483,
0.0549806795912063, 0.910518320182657, 0.1194939793847, 0.175295460825524,
0.685593423679773, 0.671682142129748, 0.279553424344115, 0.665957245629606,
0.115452197262338, 0.0964542712389723, 0.0283108105904126, 0.045686230612953,
0.239329454488972, 0.650852335308652, 0.129085041869883, 0.576503802048531,
0.845411558724963, 1.15680198554459, 0.632866328717744, 0.109898148391564,
0.487910939061688, 0.102004734166744, 1.16721621479739, 1.00082705832325,
0.211467150602276, 0.0773943989155459, 0.682644465007817, 0.153183240729545,
0.547325576464062, 0.238225871919829, 0.159445192411196, 1.13098058477778,
0.195899786158926, NA, 0.056471171238956, 0.126471254156812,
NA, 0.662802232744691, 0.0110990059628997, 0.195349021984076,
1.20932017338426, NA, 0.281021480991908, NA, 0.699824504515865,
NA, 0.398156422666091, 0.293591836627236, 0.110397085099532,
0.494151495842147, 0.990907277089313, 0.786275076845587, 0.0840744769949052,
0.660822228561536, 0.499337725955263, 0.0662268167776316, 0.373436957226925,
0.565853819066506, 0.964699228397632, 0.971176002920955, 0.458470171093662,
0.60133208657991, 0.899234051257062, 0.364765030398401, 0.439855359484562,
0.767135696394782, 0.47627256194497, 1.08942768689603, 0.00112302275044461,
0.109124234131234, 0.453261883835865, 0.278147939249062, 0.343288527072693,
0.781944424204553, 1.07263087927085, 0.450943261704409, 0.9196249283577,
0.275002110784777, 0.423170900052689, 0.338331977539611, 0.481540717547861,
1.82425307026197, 0.559509374951755, 0.263394351228691, 0.815960420377561,
0.17589288151863, 0.0881364167450121, 0.938979021291792, 1.03733665131581,
0.361367867691101, 0.00525996509392326, 1.96102257617475, 0.0218149113494686,
0.589210871333344), diffexpressed = c("Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig", "Non-Sig",
"Non-Sig"), Genes3 = c("Cask", "Ank3", "Ktn1", "R3hdm1", "Lrrfip1",
"Dst", "Clasp1", "Kif1a", "Plppr2", "Slc35a4", "Ktn1", "Agap1",
"Pfkfb2", "Cfap77", "Ank3", "Fat1", "Tns1", "Lrrfip1", "Gm28778",
"Relch", "Swi5", "Macf1", "Arhgap21", "Tsga10", "Mbnl1", "Enah",
"Rgs7", "Map4k4", "Rapgef2", "Pcdh9", "Atp6v1h", "Dclk2", "Prkar2a",
"Lrba", "Rabgap1l", "Pcdh7", "Ncam1", "Plec", "Ldah", "Gbp6",
"Agap3", "Gm43738", "Dclk1", "Klhl5", "Ppp1cc", "Rufy3", "Map4",
"Dhx37", "Rap1gds1", "Lhfpl3", "Camk2d", "Eif2b4", "0610012G03Rik",
"Specc1", "Slc12a5", "Nup205", "Dnm1", "Specc1", "Hmgb1", "Nbdy",
"Chl1", "Gm44596", "Eif4g3", "Cnbp", "Rab11fip5", "C2cd5", "Plppr3",
"Trmt1", "Slc9a3r2", "Lims1", "Pdxdc1", "Prmt5", "Acy1", "Atg4b",
"Ubxn4", "Acadl", "Fahd2a", "Slc17a6", "Rusf1", "Sh3gl3", "Serpina3k",
"Ckap5", "Inpp4a", "Cog7", "Commd5", "Jmy", "Serpina1c", "Eif4g3",
"Igsf8", "Srpk2", "Cluh", "Spag9", "Eef1d", "Ank1", "Plec", "Bscl2",
"Syncrip", "Syt2", "Mia3", "Maz"), genelabels = c(FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA,
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
Diestrus1 <- data.frame(log2FC = Diestrus_df$log.foldchange_F_dies.M,
                        logpv = -log10(Diestrus_df$pvalue))

Diestrus1$diffexpressed <- "Non-Sig"

Diestrus1$diffexpressed[Diestrus1$log2FC > 1 & Diestrus1$logpv > 1.2] <- "UP"

Diestrus1$diffexpressed[Diestrus1$log2FC < -1 & Diestrus1$logpv > 1.2] <- "DOWN"

Genes3 <- Diestrus_df$Genes

head(Genes3)

Diestrus2 <- cbind(Diestrus1, Genes3)

head(Diestrus2)

Diestrus2$genelabels <- ""
Diestrus2$genelabels <- ifelse(Diestrus2$Genes3 == "Serpina1e"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "Mtatp6"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "Cfap54"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "Camk2a"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "CSN2"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "CSN1S1"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "CSN1S2"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "Krt80"
                               |Diestrus2$Genes3 == "Galm", T, F)


options(ggrepel.max.overlaps = Inf)

ggplot(Diestrus2) + geom_point(aes(log2FC, logpv, col = diffexpressed)) + geom_text_repel(aes(log2FC, logpv), label = ifelse(Diestrus2$genelabels == TRUE, as.character(Diestrus2$Genes3), ""), box.padding = unit(0.90, "lines"), hjust = 0.40) + theme(legend.title = element_blank(), text = element_text(size = 14)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "blue"))
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoDhC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoDhC.png)

Volcano Plot displaying some

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uw6N.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uw6N.png)

Comment: Do you just want it to label the "DOWN" and "UP" points?  If not, what criterion do you want to use?  Also, we may be able to provide some advice, but without a reproducible example including the data, it will be more challenging.

Comment: Hello! I have the impression that your code is already displaying the genes correctly. What you can do is to create a function to do this automatically. This function can look like this: https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/EnhancedVolcano/inst/doc/EnhancedVolcano.html

Comment: Hi Dave, I want to create a function that will automatically display my "UP" and "DOWN", the ones labeled on my graph are from me manually going through the data and picking based on the threshold. I added a sample of my data in the main post.  @Dave

Comment: @GenesisRosiles I guess the real question is - is there some way to determine the threshold without manually looking at the data?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong so I set my threshold for my log2FC and logpv and I can order my genes by lowest to highest log2FC in the data frame which tells me the top upregulated genes but my question is how can I write a function to do that... like display first 10 genes with highest log2FC and label on VP.. sorry for the confusion not sure if I am explaining properly

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've got a potential solution.  The function below `label_sig()` takes the data, the x- and y-variables for the plot (assuming you want to label based on values of the x-variable.  It also wants the variable that identifies the label, the number of points to label and whether or not you want a plot returned.  If `TRUE`, then a ggplot is returned, otherwise, the labelled data are returned. Here's an example using your data.

```r
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggrepel)
  Diestrus1 <- structure(list(log2FC = c(-0.0794009, -0.113568, 0.615316, -1.16623, 
                                         -0.32056, -0.206217, -0.0100415, -0.0448286, -0.0486388, -0.0756063, 
                                         -0.0728393, 0.315451, 0.0426718, 0.639178, 0.0925341, 0.0450367, 
                                         0.006901, -0.0429835, 0.134707, 0.162444, 0.212584, 0.165407, 
                                         -0.0872685, 0.679763, 0.389217, -0.033093, -0.152635, -0.0211448, 
                                         0.0847027, -0.195283, 0.0832398, -0.013115, -0.100765, -0.0671384, 
                                         -0.329955, 0.0578964, -0.0457076, -0.462796, 0.316622, NA, -0.0127716, 
                                         0.15966, NA, 0.447555, -0.00621892, 0.0649842, -0.332575, NA, 
                                         0.320113, 0.589376, -0.162403, NA, -0.242632, -0.0594681, 0.0641964, 
                                         0.172721, -0.12879, -0.247723, 0.0341975, 0.948706, -0.362608, 
                                         0.0129117, 0.148919, 0.39596, -0.170329, 0.192233, 0.0750046, 
                                         0.239356, -0.113177, 0.184563, -0.0462517, 0.111383, 0.111771, 
                                         0.160304, -0.000317698, -0.0305621, 0.0506452, -0.0694846, -0.122766, 
                                         0.127085, -0.737947, 0.0698927, 0.16994, -0.291991, -0.12592, 
                                         -0.198342, -0.273148, -0.224852, -0.148406, 0.0278062, -0.12111, 
                                         0.154747, -0.0123293, -0.174397, -0.296173, -0.142334, 0.002339, 
                                         -0.28758, -0.00561539, 0.351303), 
                              logpv = c(0.117565320209322, 
                                         0.369598291242942, NA, 0.751054703257298, 2.22594458046808, 0.31656749829483, 
                                         0.0549806795912063, 0.910518320182657, 0.1194939793847, 0.175295460825524, 
                                         0.685593423679773, 0.671682142129748, 0.279553424344115, 0.665957245629606, 
                                         0.115452197262338, 0.0964542712389723, 0.0283108105904126, 0.045686230612953, 
                                         0.239329454488972, 0.650852335308652, 0.129085041869883, 0.576503802048531, 
                                         0.845411558724963, 1.15680198554459, 0.632866328717744, 0.109898148391564, 
                                         0.487910939061688, 0.102004734166744, 1.16721621479739, 1.00082705832325, 
                                         0.211467150602276, 0.0773943989155459, 0.682644465007817, 0.153183240729545, 
                                         0.547325576464062, 0.238225871919829, 0.159445192411196, 1.13098058477778, 
                                         0.195899786158926, NA, 0.056471171238956, 0.126471254156812, 
                                         NA, 0.662802232744691, 0.0110990059628997, 0.195349021984076, 
                                         1.20932017338426, NA, 0.281021480991908, NA, 0.699824504515865, 
                                         NA, 0.398156422666091, 0.293591836627236, 0.110397085099532, 
                                         0.494151495842147, 0.990907277089313, 0.786275076845587, 0.0840744769949052, 
                                         0.660822228561536, 0.499337725955263, 0.0662268167776316, 0.373436957226925, 
                                         0.565853819066506, 0.964699228397632, 0.971176002920955, 0.458470171093662, 
                                         0.60133208657991, 0.899234051257062, 0.364765030398401, 0.439855359484562, 
                                         0.767135696394782, 0.47627256194497, 1.08942768689603, 0.00112302275044461, 
                                         0.109124234131234, 0.453261883835865, 0.278147939249062, 0.343288527072693, 
                                         0.781944424204553, 1.07263087927085, 0.450943261704409, 0.9196249283577, 
                                         0.275002110784777, 0.423170900052689, 0.338331977539611, 0.481540717547861, 
                                         1.82425307026197, 0.559509374951755, 0.263394351228691, 0.815960420377561, 
                                         0.17589288151863, 0.0881364167450121, 0.938979021291792, 1.03733665131581, 
                                         0.361367867691101, 0.00525996509392326, 1.96102257617475, 0.0218149113494686, 
                                         0.589210871333344), 
                              Genes3 = c("Cask", "Ank3", "Ktn1", "R3hdm1", 
                                          "Lrrfip1", "Dst", "Clasp1", "Kif1a", "Plppr2", "Slc35a4", "Ktn1", 
                                          "Agap1", "Pfkfb2", "Cfap77", "Ank3", "Fat1", "Tns1", "Lrrfip1", 
                                          "Gm28778", "Relch", "Swi5", "Macf1", "Arhgap21", "Tsga10", "Mbnl1", 
                                          "Enah", "Rgs7", "Map4k4", "Rapgef2", "Pcdh9", "Atp6v1h", "Dclk2", 
                                          "Prkar2a", "Lrba", "Rabgap1l", "Pcdh7", "Ncam1", "Plec", "Ldah", 
                                          "Gbp6", "Agap3", "Gm43738", "Dclk1", "Klhl5", "Ppp1cc", "Rufy3", 
                                          "Map4", "Dhx37", "Rap1gds1", "Lhfpl3", "Camk2d", "Eif2b4", "0610012G03Rik", 
                                          "Specc1", "Slc12a5", "Nup205", "Dnm1", "Specc1", "Hmgb1", "Nbdy", 
                                          "Chl1", "Gm44596", "Eif4g3", "Cnbp", "Rab11fip5", "C2cd5", "Plppr3", 
                                          "Trmt1", "Slc9a3r2", "Lims1", "Pdxdc1", "Prmt5", "Acy1", "Atg4b", 
                                          "Ubxn4", "Acadl", "Fahd2a", "Slc17a6", "Rusf1", "Sh3gl3", "Serpina3k", 
                                          "Ckap5", "Inpp4a", "Cog7", "Commd5", "Jmy", "Serpina1c", "Eif4g3", 
                                          "Igsf8", "Srpk2", "Cluh", "Spag9", "Eef1d", "Ank1", "Plec", "Bscl2", 
                                          "Syncrip", "Syt2", "Mia3", "Maz")), 
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 100L))

  label_sig <- function(data, xvar, yvar, label, n=10, plot=TRUE){
    require(dplyr)
    require(ggplot2)
    require(ggrepel)
    data <- data %>% select(all_of(c(xvar, yvar, label))) %>% na.omit()
    s <- sort(abs(data[[xvar]]))
    thresh <- s[(length(s) - n)]
    data <- data %>% 
      mutate(sig = ifelse(abs(!!sym(xvar)) > thresh, 1, 0),
             lab = ifelse(sig == 1, Genes3, NA), 
             col = ifelse(sig == 1 & !!sym(xvar) < 0, "Down", "Non-sig"),
             col = ifelse(sig == 1 & !!sym(xvar) > 0, "Up", col))
    if(!plot){
      ret <- data
    }else{
      ret <- ggplot(data) + 
        geom_point(aes(!!sym(xvar), !!sym(yvar), color = col)) + 
        geom_text_repel(aes(!!sym(xvar), !!sym(yvar), label=lab), box.padding = unit(0.90, "lines"), hjust = 0.40) + 
        theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
              text = element_text(size = 14)) + 
        scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "blue"))
    }
    return(ret)
    
  }
```

First, returning a figure:

```r
  
label_sig(Diestrus1, "log2FC", "logpv", "Genes3")
#> Warning: Removed 84 rows containing missing values (`geom_text_repel()`).
```

[image]

Next, returning the labeled dataset.

```r
out <- label_sig(Diestrus1, "log2FC", "logpv", "Genes3", plot=FALSE) 
head(out)
#>       log2FC      logpv  Genes3 sig    lab     col
#> 1 -0.0794009 0.11756532    Cask   0   <NA> Non-sig
#> 2 -0.1135680 0.36959829    Ank3   0   <NA> Non-sig
#> 4 -1.1662300 0.75105470  R3hdm1   1 R3hdm1    Down
#> 5 -0.3205600 2.22594458 Lrrfip1   0   <NA> Non-sig
#> 6 -0.2062170 0.31656750     Dst   0   <NA> Non-sig
#> 7 -0.0100415 0.05498068  Clasp1   0   <NA> Non-sig
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>